# Component rendered before correct prop data is passed in from another component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a component called EditPost and that uses another component called PostForm. I am using vuex store to make an api call to retrieve the post object to be edited from the backend in the EditPost beforeCreate method and using a computed property to get the retrieved post from the store which I then pass as a prop to the PostForm component.
Since the object exists already, I want its data to be populated in the input fields of the PostForm. But the values of the object aren't there since the component is rendered before. How can I make sure the data is safely reached before the component gets rendered.

My EditPost component is basically like this:

```
<template>
    <PostForm v-bind:key="fetchPost" />
</template>

<script>
beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadPost');
}
computed: 
    fetchPost() {
        return this.$store.getters.getPost;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the `loadPost` action to be completed in `beforeCreated()`, then the component won't be created before the API responds. But be aware that this is not the best practice since the user won't see anything before the API returns a response.

Example:

```
<template>
    <PostForm v-bind:key="fetchPost" />
</template>


<script>
async beforeCreate() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('loadPost');
}
computed: 
    fetchPost() {
        return this.$store.getters.getPost;
    }

</script>
```